# Logging in and logging out in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential

New developer here . . .

In my iOS app, I want to implement a simple log-in screen that will allow the user connect to a web service that requires authentication. My plan is to create an NSURLCredential, and provide that to the web service. That part seems straight forward, but I'm not sure how to go about logging out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm not sure if this is how credentials work, but I was considering removing the credential from the NSURLCredentialStorage. Would that work as a log out?

I was also curious if there was some way to check and see if the web service session was still persisting (as if it were not, i'd like the user to have to re enter their login info).

Any help/ starting point/ tutorial would be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a well-built API based on REST principles, as many seem to be striving for these days, 
then the API won't be tracking any sessions at all, and so there's no logging out necessary.  Session management in this case would be completely up to your app to handle.  Your app would just need to "forget" the user's locally-stored credentials and display a login dialog where appropriate.

But if the service you're using manages its own sessions, then the first thing I'd look for is what URL I need to call (e.g. with NSURLConnection) to log out.